# Is it possible to pass a nested property of a hash to function in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, controller

I have this function in rails controller:

```
def validate_params(*props)
    props.each do |prop|
      unless params[prop].start_with?('abc')
        # return error
      end
    end
  end
```

im thinking if I have params[:name] and params[:bio] and I want to validate name & bio with this function (not every attribute I might want to validate), I will call it with `validate_params(:name, :bio)`. But, for nested param it won't work like `params[:user][:name]`. Is there anything I can do to pass this nested property to my function or is there a completely different approach? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rails Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) generally belong in the model. You should post some additional info about what you're trying to do. For example, if you wanted to run the validation in the controller because these validations should only run in a certain context (i.e., only when this resource is interacted with from this specific endpoint), use [on:](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on) to define custom contexts.

If you don't want to do things the rails way (which you should, imo), then don't call params in the method body. i.e.

```
def validate_params(*args)
  args.each do |arg|
    unless arg.start_with?('abc')
      # return error
    end
  end
end
```

and call with `validate_params(params[:user], params[:user][:name]`

but yeah... just do it the rails way, you'll thank yourself later.

Comment: Another way to handle validations in different contexts is through the Form Object pattern. https://nimblehq.co/blog/lets-play-design-patterns-form-objects